# How many times a ngFor tag with piping is repeated

Tags: angular, pipe, angular8, ngfor

I'm building an app in Angular 8 which primarily includes a table of data. This table is created with `<tr *ngFor="let entry of entries">`. If I want to find the number of results, it will be `entries.length`.

However, if I add a pipe in my code (`<tr *ngFor="let entry of entries | filter:searchText">`), how can I find how many times the `<tr>` div is repeated???

This number has to be displayed inside the app. It is not just for debugging.

I have to mention that this filter isn't custom. The package "*ng2-search-filter*" is used.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: In your ts file you can write some logic to find the length of the filtered entries.

Comment: Is this just for debugging or display in your app?

Comment: @1252748 This number has to be displayed inside the app. It is not just for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also write like this:
ts file:

```
filtered:any[]=[];
```

HTML file:

```
<div>total:{{filtered.length}}</div>
<tr *ngFor="let entry of entries|filter:searchText as filtered">
  <td>//something</td>
</tr>
```

OR

```
 <div>total:{{(entries|filter:searchText)?.length }}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! However, this works only inside the loop. Is there some trick to use it in another div (in the same template)??

Comment: Yeah define fitered in your ts file as empty array and use it any where

Comment: No. It doesn't work.`compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 30 in [let entry of filteredItems = (entries | filter:searchText)]`

Answer (score 1):

`ngFor` directive supports referencing the result inside of a template via `as`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | filter : dddd as filteredItems">
  {{filteredItems.length}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works if I use the `{{filteredItems.length}}` inside the loop. Is there some trick to use it in another div (in the same template)??

Comment: not this way. I'm afraid that the best option for you is to inject filterPipe to component class and apply it to array to get the filtered array